# C# Generic class, but how?

Tags: c#, class, generics, reflection, properties

I have a problem with which I can't get any further. Google brings me a lot of results, but I can't really get by.

I've tried different things with `generic` classes and `reflections`. Nothing worked. I have again minimized the following example so that only the most important things remain. I would be grateful for the help.

```
public class TestData1
{
    public long Id { get; set; } = 0;
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Fullname { get; set; }
    public string Beruf { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
}

public class TestData2
{
    public long Id { get; set; } = 0;
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Fullname { get; set; }
}



public class Doit
{

    public Doit( ) {

        // init two different classes with data
        TestData1 td1 = new TestData1 {Firstname="Roland", Name="Smith", Beruf="Developer"};
        TestData2 td2 = new TestData2 {Firstname="Petra", Name="Summer" };
            
        // call the function to do the same action with the different classes
        TestData1 tf1 = TestFunc<TestData1>(td1, "OtherParams" );
        TestData2 tf2 = TestFunc(td2, "OtherParams");

    }
    


    /// <summary>
    /// Example 
    /// All entries dosn't work. :(
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="prog"></param>
    /// <param name="textInserts"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private T TestFunc<T>( T prog, string textInserts = null ) where T : class {
        string prgname = prog.GetType().Name;    // typeof(prog).Name;

        // Get two propertiers from the class. Ths properties aare in 
        //  all classes the same.
        var aa = T.Firstname;
        var bb = T.Name;

        // do somethin with the class and the properties
        T.Fullname = $"{aa} {bb}";

        // Do some others with the class and the properties.

        // return the class with the changed data
        return T;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not saying what you intend to do. Please edit your question to include the expected result.

Comment: You'll need a common base class.

Comment: This sounds like an XY Problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a base class or an interface: either works. Let's use a base class for simplicity:

```
public class TestDataBase
{
    public long Id { get; set; } = 0;
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Fullname { get; set; }
}

public class TestData1 : TestDataBase
{
    public string Beruf { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
}

public class TestData2 : TestDataBase
{
}
```

Then you can add a generic type constraint of `TestDataBase`:

```
private T TestFunc<T>(T prog, string textInserts = null) where T : TestDataBase
{
    string prgname = typeof(T).Name;

    // Access properties on 'TestDataBase'
    prog.FullName = $"{prog.FirstName} {prog.Name}";

    return prog;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply.

But access to the individual properties does not work that way either. Returning the class doesn't work either.

roland

Comment: How can I access individual properties. I still have to process the class. So I have to access properties (after test)

roland

Comment: @RolandKruggel What do you mean, "doesn't work"? See here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jrOxIO

Comment: Sorry I don't think my example was optimal. I also want to access properties that are not in TestDataBase. They should be tested beforehand and then, if available, they should be used.

e.g.
```
            // Do some others with the class and the properties.
            if(prog.Date) {
                prog.Date = prog.Date.AddDays( 2 );
            }

```
roland

Comment: `if (prog is TestData1 testData1) { testData1.SomeProperty = Something; }`?

Comment: Hello,

Thank you very much for the help. It has brought me a long way. The problem is solved. I hope my solution is not too cumbersome.

roland

Comment: ```
private T TestFunc<T>( T prog, string textInserts = null ) where T : TestDataBase {
    prog.Fullname = $"{prog.Firstname} {prog.Name}";
    PropertyInfo pi = prog.GetType().GetProperty("Date");
    if( pi != null && pi.CanWrite ) {                
        var dat = pi.GetValue(prog); 
        DateTime ui = (DateTime)Convert.ChangeType( dat, pi.PropertyType );
        DateTime uii = ui.AddDays(2);
        pi.SetValue( prog, uii, null );
    }
    return prog;
}
```

Comment: @RolandKruggel That's unnecessarily complex. Why not define an interface `interface IHasDate { DateTime Date { get; set; } }`, then all types which have the `Date` property implement `IHasDate`, then you can do `if (prog is IHasDate hasDate) { hasDate.Date = ....; }`?